# Convergence of conditional probability given convergence of the conditional event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

Consider a sequence of random variables $X_n$ that converges in probability to a random variable $X$. Is it true that for all measurable events $A$ we have the convergence:

$$\mathbb P(A | X, X_n) \rightarrow^p \mathbb P(A|X)$$

If not, what conditions do I need to make this true?

I would expect that it is true, but I am not sure what the exact argument is and if I am missing some subtle point.

To show the convergence, we need to show that for all $\epsilon >0$ we have that $\mathbb P( | \mathbb P(A | X, X_n) - \mathbb P(A|X) | > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$. Here is my attempt:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb P( | \mathbb P(A | X, X_n) - \mathbb P(A|X) | > \epsilon) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb P( | \mathbb P(A | \delta_n, X) - \mathbb P(A|X) | > \epsilon)$$

where $\delta_n = X -X_n$. But $\delta_n \rightarrow^p 0$. From here I would want to bring the limit on the RHS inside the expectation, but for that I'm pretty sure I need convergence almost surely of $\delta_n$. After that I would be done. Am I missing something, or do I really need convergence almost surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.  Let $\mathbb{P}(A) \in (0,1)$ and consider the random variables $X_n := \frac 1n 1_A$.  Then $(X_n) \rightarrow 0$ a.s. and therefore also in probability, but $\mathbb{P}(A | X_n) = 1_A$ so $\mathbb{P}(A | X_n) \not \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A|X) = \mathbb{P}(A)$.